# How to correctly stream audio using the html 5 audio object

Tags: android, html, audio, stream

I currently can stream audio using an html 5 object, short snippet of code below.

```
let snd = new Audio("data:audio/wav;base64," + this.hexToBase64(this.waveHeader + this.byteStream));
snd.play();
```

Unfortunately I am encountering this error and I have made a post found at [STREAM- DOMException: play() can only be initiated by a user gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48293149/stream-domexception-play-can-only-be-initiated-by-a-user-gesture)

```
`this.byteStream` is a buffered 0.1 (s) of audio data in hex
```

So far, I reconstruct a new file each time I want to play 0.1 (s) of audio stream, so I thought how is this really streaming? Wouldn't the best approach to this be somehow to create an audio object `once` give it a wave header + initial data and somehow tell the audio object, for each new data appended continously play it. So I hit .play() once, and each time I append data it plays it. This would put the buffer responsibility on the API.

That would be so nice, is this possible? This would also fix my problem as the .play() method is only called once

Update : I decided to add an event, such that when you click anywhere the code is ran.

```
<div id="container" [style.background]="getContainerStyle()" (click) = "start()">
```

start(), ran my program like normal before encapsulated inside the event. Still did not work.